SQL query to print aggregated data by date adjacent to each other
I have a SQL table similar to below



id
item
date




1
item1
date1


2
item2
date1


3
item3
date3


4
item4
date4


5
item3
date4



If wanted to print how many items exist for each date, I can do a simple group by and sum on date and I will get something like below



date
count




date1
2


date3
1


date4
2



My goal is to have data displayed in below form for each date(count) and also for date-7 days



date
count
date-7
count(date-7)




date1
2
date1-7
count for date1-7


date3
1
date3-7
count for date3-7


date4
2
date4-7
count for date4-7



How do I frame such a query?

Please show the dates rather than just writing "date1" etc. Can those dates overlap each other? How to count them in this case?  Please show real sample data and descibe all possible use cases you need to cover. Also tag your RDBMS because especially date functions differ a lot.

Thanks @JonasMetzler. Let us say date is just a string in the format yyy-mm-dd and is of type varchar. This is databricks though.

share sample data @curiousengineer

Why store dates as string in a varchar column? Just don't. Use a date column and store dates.
